# PHP/SQL - Recursively downing SQL values regarding a huge amount and a max quota

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am currently developping a web-based browser game using SVG, JQuery/Ajax, PHP & SQL and I am stuck in a problem :

Value to affect recursively : -75 (Health Point)
My values are between 1 a 50 (Health Point).

For example (ID | Health Point) :

```
1 | 50
2 | 1
3 | 25
4 | 4
5 | 16
```

I want, in SQL, without any PHP while(), to organise my data from the lowest HP value to the highest value to get that :

```
2 | 1
4 | 4
5 | 16
3 | 25
1 | 50
```

And then, to recursively subtract value without going into negative values.
Example :

```
2 | 0 (74 hp to subtract left)
4 | 0 (70 hp to subtract left)
5 | 0 (54 hp to subtract left)
3 | 0 (29 hp to subtract left)
1 | 21 (0 hp to subtract left)
```

A last condition is to have a "limiter" of hp lost for each "character". For example, if I have to subtract 2000 hp for 100 players that have between 1 and 200 hp. The "limiter" will be 2000 / 100 = 20 hp max lost per character. But this number have to update on each subtract. It means that, in this example, if 700 hp remain for 2 players, then the limiter will be 350.

But I don't know how to do this. Is it possible ? The easiest way is to do a simple PHP while but having more than 2k row, I'm affraid it's not the best way to do this.

Comment: ""I want, in SQL, without any PHP while(), to organise my data from the lowest HP value to the highest value to get that : `.... ORDER BY hp DESC`?

Comment: "A last condition is to have a "limiter" of hp lost for each "character"" How does a "character" looks like i don't see a character_id or something like that in the database to indentify that case.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want a cumulative sum and subtraction.  One method uses variables:

```
select t.*, (@sum := @sum + points) as running_sum
from (select t.*
      from t
      order by t.points asc
     ) t cross join
     (select @sum := 0);
```

Then, you want the difference from -75, so something like:

```
select t.*,
       greatest((@sum := @sum + points) - 75, 0) as your_value
from (select t.*
      from t
      order by t.points asc
     ) t cross join
     (select @sum := 0);
```

Note:  The syntax is a bit cleaner in MySQL 8+:

```
select t.*,
       greatest(sum(points) over (order by points asc) - 75, 0) as your_value
from t;
```

Comment: It may work. Cannot test it because I got the error "#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias". Also, in my problem, I want to start from the lowest one, so I think the best way to do it is to use LEAST() instead of GREATEST(). Any idea ?

Comment: @P.Jerome . . . Every derived table in this answer *does* have an alias.  `greatest()` is needed to return `0` when the result is negative.